# How to restart a specific service in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was looking forward to know, how can i restart a specific service in a docker-compose.yaml file for example

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
  -grid-shared:

services:

  service-A:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ../../Dockerfile
  service-B:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ../../Dockerfile
  service-C:
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: ../../Dockerfile
```

After i run docker-compose up
I mad some changes in service-A Dockerfile file and now i want to sync my changes to only that container

Comment: Just re-running `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` will rebuild the images (fast if they're unchanged) and recreate only the containers that have changed.  In your case, since all three containers are running the same image, you'll always restart all of them.

Comment: @DavidMaze the images are different and i am running some local service for example http or grpc etc etc. i was looking foward to know if i made any changes in those local file for example i added an extra endpoint for a restapi in service-A, in that case how can i sync only that changes to my running container because i cant build the entire service since it takes a lot time.

Comment: `the images are different` <= not according to your example. Please provide a correct [mre]. Please also note that, although not invalid, your service names are weird. I is unusual to have a service name starting with a dash (`-` as in `"-service-C"`).

Comment: @Zeitounator i guess it does make sense now. basically i am running lots of services just for example consider this. as i have told you i made some local changes for instance service-C now i want to sync that change to my container but i dont want to re-build the entire docker-compose file consider the exmple as docker-compose.yaml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `docker-compose restart service-A` for [restarting](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_restart/) containers but am not sure if this will trigger a build.

You might end up using the same cached service.

But what will work for sure is `docker-compose down service-A`

and then `docker-compose up --build service-A`